# I want to sort a JSON in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, sorting

I have a following JSON which need to be sorted in alphabetical order(based on value),

```
{ 
   1: "Your Professional",
   2: "Describing Clothes", 
   3: "Describing People", 
   4: "At the Doctor", 
   5: "At the supermarket", 
   6: "Cooking", 
   7: "After work", 
   8: "Describing Objects and Places", 
   9: "Asking Questions", 
  10: "A city tour" 
}
```

The JSON is sorted by the key, but I want to sort it with the `value` in alphabetical order.

**My expectation** is(sorted based on `value`),

```
{ 
   10: "A city tour", 
   7: "After work", 
   9: "Asking questions", 
   4: "At the Doctor", 
   5: "At the supermarket", 
   6: "Cooking", 
   2: "Describing clothes", 
   8: "Describing Objects and Places", 
   3: "Describing People", 
   1: "Your Professional"
}
```

It will be very much helpful, if anyone guide me on this.

Comment: What you have looks more like a JS object. JS objects don't have any specific order, hence you can't sort an object. Reodrering a JSON string would be more or less fruitless, since when it is converted to an object, the order of the keys is not guaranteed to be preserved.

Comment: That's not valid JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [`sort()` documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

```
var items = [
  { name: "Edward", value: 21 },
  { name: "Sharpe", value: 37 },
  { name: "And", value: 45 },
  { name: "The", value: -12 },
  { name: "Magnetic", value: 13 },
  { name: "Zeros", value: 37 }
];
items.sort(function (a, b) {
  return a.value - b.value;
});
```

So let's translate it to your use case :

```js
const objFromJson = { 
   1: "Your Professional",
   2: "Describing Clothes", 
   3: "Describing People", 
   4: "At the Doctor", 
   5: "At the supermarket", 
   6: "Cooking", 
   7: "After work", 
   8: "Describing Objects and Places", 
   9: "Asking Questions", 
  10: "A city tour" 
}
let ar = []

// convert your object into an array of objects
for (const key in objFromJson) {
  ar.push({ id: key, value: objFromJson[key] })
}

console.log(ar)

// sort by value
ar.sort(function (a, b) {
  return a.value > b.value;
});

console.log(ar)
```

Comment: How is `sort` related to objects?

Comment: Consider adding some explanation to avoid a down vote.

Comment: by an `Array.from` if you want to

Comment: Updated it to address the issue. Sorry if it was too concise

Comment: @3Dos Thanks alot for your quick answer. Can you explain this part please 

`for (const key in objFromJson) {
  ar.push({ id: key, value: objFromJson[key] })
}`  

how should I pass the key and value there?

Comment: Here's [the documentation of for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in). What I do with it is simply building an `array` so I can sort it. You can rename `key` whatever you want...

Comment: Thanks @3Dos, your answer helped me alot and now my problem got solved.

Answer (score 4):

If you have access to the backend I would send it as an array, as JSON isn't sorted.

If you have to do it on the client, however:

```
const myJSON = {1: 'Key one', 2: 'Key two'}
const sorted = Object.keys(myJSON)
  .map(Number)
  .sort((a, b)=> b - a)
  .map(item=> {
    const obj = {}
    obj[item] = myJSON[item]
    return obj
  })
```

If you can use an array just do

```
.map(item => myJSON[item])
```